# Haskell: recursive mapping difficulty

Tags: haskell, recursion, mapping

I'm working on recursive tree walking. I want something like the following (Haskell pseudocode):

```
walkTree step root = do
  dsc <- getDescendants root
  for d in dsc
    nextStep = increase step d
    walkTree nextStep d
```

No iteration for me, of course. I can't figure out the mapping solution, though. How can I manage the `step` thing?

UPD:

Let's try the mapping:

```
walkTree step root = do
  dsc <- getDescendants root
  nextStep = increase step d
  mapM (walkTree nextStep) dsc
```

Two problems: `nextStep` is frozen for the mapping; also cannot get `d` (which is secondary)

Comment: Please always add type signatures and reference or definitions for all data you're dealing with.

Comment: This is pseudocode, isn't it? `root` is a tree node, `dsc` is a list of its immediate descendants, `step` is something else yet subject to change and passing on.

Comment: It's ok to post pseudocode for your solution attempt, but we still need to know properly what data structures you're talking about, and what the _purpose_ (i.e. type signature) of your algorithm would be.

Comment: what does it mean to `increase` a descendant? Or do you `increase` a `step`? what does it mean?

Comment: I `increase` just `step`. `step` is something which gets changed on every iteration via `increase`. Let us forget about `d` as the second argument to `increase` for the time being. See the UPD

Comment: The pseudocode just looks like `mapM (\d -> let nextStep = increase step d in walkTree nextStep d) dsc` to me. If this doesn't work, then I would guess it is your algorithm (and not your implementation) which is wrong. It's unclear what function you're actually trying to implement though; "recursive tree walking" is not very standard terminology (is it DFS? BFS? something else?)

Comment: Looks very much like it. I'm going to try and make a report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final solution, courtesy of [user2407038](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2407038/user2407038) (see comments to the question). This is a snippet of running code (is it DFS?):

```
-- | Walks the source tree, recreates source tree at destination.
traverseTreeDst :: Settings -> FilePath -> Int -> Int -> Counter -> FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
traverseTreeDst args dstRoot total totw counter dstStep srcDir = do
  (dirs, files)        <- listDir args srcDir

  let traverse dir = do
        let step = dstStep </> basename dir
        mkdir (dstRoot </> step)
        traverseTreeDst   args dstRoot total totw counter step dir

  mapM_ traverse                                                   dirs
  mapM_ (copyFile         args dstRoot total totw counter dstStep) files
```

You probably see why I resorted to pseudocode. Lots of unnecessary detail, yet this is it. The thing copies audio files, mangles their names, and sets tags. Nothing much.

I wouldn't mind discussing the relevant terminology. How do you describe this kind of problem and this kind of solution?